# Undefined index when inserting into database

Tags: php, mysql

I have a function where people can insert two textfields into the database. It inserts empty fields into the database at the moments at gives me these errors right now:

Notice: Undefined variable: catchphrase in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/modul8B/controllers/home.php on line 17

Notice: Undefined variable: interest in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/modul8B/controllers/home.php on line 17

Notice: Undefined variable: image in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/modul8B/controllers/home.php on line 17

Here's the form:

```
<?php
include_once 'models/profile_table_class.php';

return"
<div class='main-wrap'>
    <div class='container'>



      <div class='header'>




            <form id='profile-form' method=post action='index.php?page=home' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
                <h1> Your Profile </h1> 
                   <textarea name='catchphrase' id='catchphrase'>

                    </textarea>

                    <textarea name='interest' id='about-you' >

                    </textarea>

                    <h3 class='upload-heading'>Upload Image:</h3>
                    <input type='file' name='image' id='file'>

                    <input id='profile-submit' type='submit' value='profile-submit'/>
             </form>

       </div>
    </div>            
</div>
";
```

Here's the script for inserting the data:

```
class Profile_Table {
    private $db; 

    public function __construct($pdo) {
        $this->db = $pdo; 
        ;
    }
    public function insertProfile( $catchphrase, $interest, $image){
        $sql = "INSERT INTO profile (catchphrase, interest, image) Values ('".$catchphrase."', '".$interest."', '".$image."')";
        $statement = $this->db->prepare($sql);
        $data = array ($catchphrase, $interest, $image);  
        $statement->execute ($data);
        return $statement;
    }
```

And here's the code where the error is coming from:

```
include_once "models/profile_table_class.php";
    $profile = new Profile_Table($db);


$profileIsSubmitted = isset($_POST['profile-submit']);
if ($profileIsSubmitted) {
    $catchphrase = $_POST ['catchphrase'];
    $interest = $_POST ['interest'];
    $image = $_POST ['image'];

}  try {
        $profile->insertProfile($catchphrase, $interest, $image);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        $errorDescription = $e;
        echo $e;
    }
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: put db fields and table names in backticks or single quotes

Comment: Why is there a space in between `$_POST [`? Not sure if that's causing the error though. You could do a `var_dump($_POST);` just to check if your values are getting sent right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the try catch in the if condition. If the request is get you will have errors.

```
if ($profileIsSubmitted) {
    $catchphrase = $_POST ['catchphrase']; // and remove space
    $interest = $_POST ['interest'];// and remove space
    $image = $_POST ['image'];// and remove space

    try {
        $profile->insertProfile($catchphrase, $interest, $image);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        $errorDescription = $e;
        echo $e;
    }
}
```

Comment: okay man, the undefined indexes is removed now, but the form still send empty rows to the database. Any ideas?

Comment: Make sure the fields actually exist in `$_POST` as suggested in another comment. Use `var_dump`.

Comment: Another point your `image` is an uploaded file, use [`$_FILES`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.files.php) instead.

Comment: the var_dump doesn't show anything. after I changed the code as shown (with removed spaces- feeling stupid) it doesn't upload anything, not even the empty rows.

Comment: Change `method=post` to `method='post'` maybe. Otherwise you can close your php tag after `include_once` and put html (remove the return). You don't have php in this part.

Comment: It still doesn't upload anything. My current datatypes for both textfields are varchar. Should I change these to text?

Comment: Where is the problem now ? Data retrieve with $_POST should work. But $_FILES is an array (refer to the php documentation). Save the path where you move file in your database.

Comment: ticked your answer.. silly mistake there: forgot the name="" in the form itself. Cheers man!